# VSCode mouse-over information for python

Tags: python, dart, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I recently started using Dart and Flutter for Mobile App dev on VSCode, and I love how the mouse-over tooltip for methods shows return type, expected parameters, and the source of the method:

[image]

I understand that Python is not a strongly typed language so showing type information is not possible for variables. But what about methods in python?

[image]

The information in mouse-over tooltip seems extremely hard to read, and not really helpful. I don't know where the method came from and what it outputs. The description is also not very readable. Am I doing something wrong, or is this really not a feature? Or do I just need to learn to read that tooltip?

Comment: I know this isn't a complete answer, but you **can** show types for functions you've written in python if you'd like to. You can use something called type hints, which you can read more on here https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: it conveys the exact same info ... there are just more arguments... you can see types and defaults as well ... whats not useful about that? that tells me exactly how to call the method ... anyway its not magic, its really just controlled by the method declaration and any docstrings not VScode so much... if you had `def initializeApp(name:str, fireBaseOptions:FireBaseOptions=None)` the tooltip would be exactly as readable as flutters

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is the behaviour when using Jedi.

You can refer to this [page](https://github.com/pappasam/jedi-language-server/issues/227) for more details.

I suggest you using [Pylance](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.vscode-pylance) as language server. Adding the following codes to your settings.json:

```
"python.languageServer": "Pylance"
```